# SQL query with AND/OR logical operators

Tags: sql, intersection, logical-operators, disjoint-union

fI have what seems to be a relatively simple AND/OR clause that is giving me a bit of a headache.

```
$query = "SELECT stv.name,stc.tmplvarid,stc.contentid,stv.type,stv.display,stv.display_params,stc.value";
$query .= " FROM ".$tb1." stc LEFT JOIN ".$tb2." stv ON stv.id=stc.tmplvarid ";
$query .= " LEFT JOIN $tb_content tb_content ON stc.contentid=tb_content.id ";
$query .= " WHERE stv.name='".$region."' AND stc.contentid IN (".implode($cIDs,",").") ";
$query .= " OR stv.name='".$countries."' AND stc.contentid IN (".implode($cIDs,",").") ";
$query .= " AND tb_content.pub_date >= '$pub_date' ";
$query .= " AND tb_content.published = 1 ";
$query .= " ORDER BY stc.contentid ASC;";
```

I need it to retrieve the values from both `$region` and `$countries`. However, the way it is it only returns the value of `$countries`. If I remove the line with the `OR` it returns the value of `$region`, but it won't return both. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

Try putting brackets around the clauses on either side of the `OR`. See below:

```
$query = "SELECT stv.name,stc.tmplvarid,stc.contentid,stv.type,stv.display,stv.display_params,stc.value"; 
$query .= " FROM ".$tb1." stc LEFT JOIN ".$tb2." stv ON stv.id=stc.tmplvarid "; 
$query .= " LEFT JOIN $tb_content tb_content ON stc.contentid=tb_content.id "; 
$query .= " WHERE (stv.name='".$region."' AND stc.contentid IN (".implode($cIDs,",").")) "; 
$query .= " OR (stv.name='".$countries."' AND stc.contentid IN (".implode($cIDs,",").")) "; 
$query .= " AND tb_content.pub_date >= '$pub_date' "; 
$query .= " AND tb_content.published = 1 "; 
$query .= " ORDER BY stc.contentid ASC;";
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still only returning $countries. Here's the function in it's entirety if that's helpful: http://pastebin.com/E4CdnQNj

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing parentheses, no?

*A or B and C or D* is ambiguous, you need to use parentheses to make it clear you mean *(A or B) and (C or D)*